# In PostgreSQL, what is the datetime format for 2019-04-23T22:34:40.253-05:00?

Tags: postgresql, datetime-format, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to run SQL in which one selected column is of type `datetime`.

I want to select it as string, so I am using `to_char`. I pass the column name, but am stuck with the second parameter of `to_char`

The final string should be formatted like this

```
2019-04-23T22:34:40.253-05:00
```

What is the format I need to pass to as second argument to `to_char()` in PostgreSQL?

```
to_char(create_date, '???')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be your solution:

```
SELECT to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.MSTZH:TZM');

            to_char            
-------------------------------
 2019-05-14T11:52:57.470+02:00
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Laurenz Albe's answer is the way to go in Postgres 11 and above. But apparently `TZH` and `TZM` are unknown in older versions. Instead `OF` can be used there. The only problem with `OF` is, that it displays the offset hours only for some time zones (couldn't really find a pattern for that). So you have to append the minutes manually if they aren't there.

```
select to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.MS')
       || CASE
            WHEN to_char(now(), 'OF') LIKE '%:%' THEN 
              to_char(now(), 'OF')
            ELSE
              to_char(now(), 'OF') || ':00'
          END;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=d3ff940c65cf8102859f16c1b299f4bc)